# Is \baselineskip automatically defined?

Tags: macros

Is `\baselineskip` automatically defined by LaTeX?  What does it depend on?

I was going through the [`Wikibook` section regarding lengths](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths), and I just realized also that `\bigskip` and others are not dependent on the font size.  Is this the same for `baselineskip`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`\baselineskip` is a tex primitive, so it is always defined to be something (well unless someone goes `\let\baselineskip\@undefined` but even then the underlying register still has a value even if it is not accessible.

It is set in various places in LaTeX, most notably all font size commands end up executing

```
\fontsize{aaa}{bbb}\selectfont
```

in which case `\baselineskip` gets set to bbb times the current value of `\baselinestretch`.

Comment: But is it defined by the size of a strut or something (maximum height and depth of a character at some point size)? My `\showthe\baselineskip` yields `13.20007pt.`, but where is TeX coming up with this value? I guess that this is perhaps a complicated question, because the LaTeX kernel (size11.clo) specifies `\baselineskip`, but how does TeX do it (since it is always defined to be something)?

Comment: @macmadness86 every size command such as `\normalsize` or `\large` or `\fontsize{1in}{2in}\selectfont` sets it (to 2in in the last case)  so normally they are set to values specified in the class.

Answer (score 23):

Let's make the example with a standard class, `article` or `report`. An option such as `10pt` (which is the default), `11pt` or `12pt` instructs LaTeX to read `size10.clo`, `size11.clo` or `size12.clo` (they would be `bkXY.clo` for the `book` class, `memoir` has a similar method).

In `size10.clo` we find

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize
```

The first instruction of `\normalsize` tells LaTeX that the main font size is 10pt (`\@xpt`) with a baseline skip of 12pt (`\@xiipt`). The value given to `\baselineskip`, though, will be multiplied by the current value of `\baselinestretch`.

In `size11.clo` and `size12.clo` the corresponding lines are

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xipt{13.6}%
   ...}
```

and

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xiipt{14.5}%
   ...}
```

respectively.

Subsequently the files define also `\large`, `\small` and similar commands, again with a `\@setfontsize` command that establishes the font size and the baseline skip.

This has a consequence: if you try changing the default baseline skip with a command such as

```
\setlength{\baselineskip}{13pt}
```

in the preamble, it will have *no* effect because `\begin{document}` issues `\normalsize`. Placing the command after `\begin{document}` will have effect, but a font size change command at the outer level will revert to the value established in the `.clo` file.

For changing the baseline skip it's better to act with `\linespread` in the preamble, which sets a value for `\baselinestretch`, used by the font size changing commands, as seen.

So if you want 10/13 typesetting instead of 10/12, issue

```
\linespread{1.08333}
```

since 12*1.08333=12.99996 which is sufficiently close to 13.

Alternatively, redefine all those commands taking inspiration from the `.clo` files.